# Converting raw sql to sql alchemy not giving the same results

Tags: sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to convert an sql query into sqlalchemy's syntax but I'm not getting the same results. The sql query is returning the four test rows that I need, while the python is returning only two. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM POW p
    JOIN completed_course cc1 on p.student_id = cc1.student_id
    JOIN term_course tc on cc1.term_course_id = tc.id
    JOIN completed_course cc on tc.id = cc.term_course_id
    LEFT JOIN specialization_course sc on tc.course_id = sc.course_id 
       AND sc.specialization_id = p.specialization_id
    WHERE p.id = 1;
```

Flask SQLAlchemy:

```
    def get(self, pow_id):
    try:
        cc = aliased(CompletedCourse)
        cc1 = aliased(CompletedCourse)
        p = aliased(POW)
        tc = aliased(TermCourse)
        sc = aliased(SpecializationCourse)
        results = p.query\
            .join(cc, cc.student_id == p.student_id)\
            .join(tc, tc.id == cc.term_course_id)\
            .join(cc1, cc1.term_course_id == tc.id)\
            .join(sc, and_(sc.course_id == tc.course_id, sc.specialization_id == p.specialization_id), isouter=True)\
            .filter(p.id == pow_id)\
            .all()
        print(results)
        return {}, 200
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("")
```

Comment: I don't see that statement WHERE p.id = 1 in SQLAlchemy

Comment: The filter is supposed to take care of that I think. I do have it in the wrong spot, I figured that out and am about to update the question, but now it results in two entries instead of the four I should be getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use db connection if you want like below code:

```
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor =conn.cursor()

sql_query = """SELECT * FROM POW p
    JOIN completed_course cc1 on p.student_id = cc1.student_id
    JOIN term_course tc on cc1.term_course_id = tc.id
    JOIN completed_course cc on tc.id = cc.term_course_id
    LEFT JOIN specialization_course sc on tc.course_id = sc.course_id 
       AND sc.specialization_id = p.specialization_id
    WHERE p.id = 1;"""

cursor.execute(sql_query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

### for flask_sqlalchemy , I used the below

sqlText = db.text(original_sql)

db.session.execute(sqlText)